# @font-face issue in IE7

Tags: font-face, internet-explorer-7, webfonts

I've got a crush on a certain font named "Kimberly" and I'm trying to use it on a heading / motto of a website. 
Applying the `@font-face` css rule worked for all browsers except IE7 where the heading isn't displayed at all, not even with a fallback font.

And what's most annyoing is that other page [ an example page downloaded from fontsquirrel.com after the conversion of the .ttf font into .eot ] works perfectly on all browsers versions.

Have anyone been through something similar?

[Please, take a look.](http://pelerinaje.tapet-online.ro)

Thanks

Comment: Did I miss something? I don't see where you have a fall back font defined? `font-family: 'kimberleyregular';` (style.css:14)...

Comment: You've probably missed it. I've set `Impact` as the fallback font and it's written as a conditional ie7 rule in the head section of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `zoom: 1` to the elements that are using your custom font. So for example:

```
#motto {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: "kimberleyregular", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Whatever you're doing, you're doing it good. I've lost ~ 2-3 hours by trying to find a solution or a workaround and you've answered in 7 minutes since I've posted the question. Again, thanks a lot! :)